# Trying to get all values of a specific key in a MongoDB Collection using Distinct(), but I'm getting a cursor as the result instead of an array

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with C# MongoDB Driver v2.13.

I'm trying to get the values of a specific key in a MongoDB Collection using Distinct(), but I'm getting a cursor as the result instead of an array.

My code:

```
var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("<connectionstring>");
var dbClient = new MongoClient(settings);
var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("players");
var newcollec = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("sampleplayer");
FieldDefinition<BsonDocument, int > field = "Salary";
var test = newcollec.Distinct(field, new BsonDocument());
```

I'm expecting to get an array with all the values, but I'm getting `` MongoDB.Driver.SingleBatchAsyncCursor`1[System.Int32] ``

Comment: The [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_Distinct_1.htm) indicate it should return IEnumerable.  SingleBatchAsyncCursor does implement that interface.

Comment: thanks but how can I get the values from it

Answer (score 0):

How about add `ToList()` in the end ?

```
var test = newcollec.Distinct(field, new BsonDocument()).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried that it returns a list but i can't access the values of the list

Comment: @pythonDON Could you show your test data model and expected result

Comment: I try your code with `ToList()` in the end. It works fine to me, i can get a list of int.

Comment: yes but how did you see it? did you write to console? display it in winforms
?

Comment: i want to sum all the values store it in a variable and display in winforms

Comment: After execute that line, i just hover my mouse on `test` and it shows the detail of the variable

Answer (score 0):

to return a single data from collection

`var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newcollec);                                         return data;`

to return full data from collection

`var dotNetObjList = newcollec.ConvertAll(BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue);                                    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dotNetObjList); return data;`